# How does triticale differ from rye in technique and flavour?

Tags: adjuncts, sparge, rye

[Radical Brewing](http://www.radicalbrewing.com/) says that [triticale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triticale) is a useful alternative to rye.  Apparently it's a rye-wheat hybrid, and is easier to sparge than rye, while still having a good rye flavour.  I'm interested in trying it, but I would like to know:

- How close are the flavours?  What are the main differences?
- Is it technically similar to rye in terms of how it should be brewed?  Is the sparge easier?
- How easy is it to get hold of malted triticale (I'm in the UK)?  Is this a better bet than flaked, or are they similar in outcome?

Answer (score 2):

**Quick Version**

I don't know about the flavour.

As long as you are using it with a base malt you can use up to ~50%, you don't need to get malted triticale or pre-cook it(see below). Also, I have no idea where you could find some in the UK; if you can find some flaked then try that.

PS: if you know where to find some please post a link here, because I am now rather interested in trying it too.

**Extended Info**

I currently know nothing about the falvours, but regarding the techniques I have found a reference. Brewing: New Techniques edited by C Bamforth Section **3.4.1 Unmalted Triticale**:

"Most non-malt adjuncts do not contribute either enzyme activity or soluble nitrogen ... triticale goes beyond this specification ... Because of this and the low gelitinisation range of triticale starch(59-65C)... triticale could be used as a brewing adjunct at high ratios(<30-50%) ... furthermore, because of its low gelatinisation temperature, triticale can be added directly to the mash tun, without the need for a cereal cooker or second mashing vessel"

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gcJQAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=gelatinisation+tricalate&source=bl&ots=u-8qrBrmGl&sig=e0n5SjJQ22lwfnp6Y97pBMjFMXU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e0yWVYy2H6zg7QaosZyQAg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=gelatinisation%20tricalate&f=false